# In-built Enterprise Edition procedures not available

Tags: neo4j

I am currently working on a project on access control in graph databases for uni. For this purpose I received an Enterprise Edition license for Neo4j. I set it up on both Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows, but my problem appears on both machines.

I was looking at property-level access control and did everything according to the manual (https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/property-level-access-control/), but it seems like the config is not loaded as the users can always read every property. When trying to call dbms.listConfig() I get an error saying the procedure does not exist. It is also not listed in the dbms.procedures list. So I suspect the problem lies somewhere "deeper".

Where could I have gone wrong? I've been browsing manuals for hours, but nothing seems to work. Is there a way that I am really using the Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the neo4j server for changes in neo4j.conf file to take effect.
And verify whether you are admin before calling CALL dbms.listConfig()
Check this link for additional support - https://maxdemarzi.com/2018/03/12/keeping-properties-secret-in-neo4j/